# Android studio aar modules

Tags: java, android-studio, aar

Been having some trouble understanding the concept of aar modules in android studio (after being with Eclipse for many years).

Say i import aar file as a module to my project with "app" being the application.

1. Can the app use code which is in the module jars or only use source in code in that aar?
2. If i use activities which are in the aar in my "app" do i need to add them in the "app" manifast?
3. If i have a compiled jars in the "app" that are the also compiled in the aar can it cause trouble?
4. Jars which are used in the aar should also added to the "app"

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I have an example [for packaging the dependencies](https://gist.github.com/qrtt1/25a44fa29e46a5ec7f5b) into AAR file.
Just make two extra tasks for copy 3rd JARs into ./build/intermediates/bundles/$BUILD/libs/ path, before gradle bundling the libs/ into AAR.